# Weak convergence of measures implies convergence of expectation of continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ be a compact metric space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. Let $\mu_n(n=1,2, \ldots)$ be a sequence of probability measures on $(E, \Sigma)$ which converges weakly to the probability measure $\mu$. $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $E' \in \Sigma$ are such that $E'$ is closed and $f$ restricted to $E'$ is continuous.

Is the following true?

$$\int\limits_{E'} f d\mu_n \rightarrow\int\limits_{E'} f d\mu$$

Motivation: I'm trying to apply Lusin's theorem in the context of some problem.

My attempt at a proof: Consider the measurable space $(E', \Sigma')$ where:

$$\Sigma' = \{A \cap E': A \in \Sigma\}$$

Let $\widetilde{\mu}_n$ and $\widetilde{\mu}$ respectively denote $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ restricted to $\Sigma'$. Obviously, $\widetilde{\mu}_n$ and $\widetilde{\mu}$ need not be probability measures on $(E', \Sigma')$.

Clearly, $\Sigma' \subseteq \Sigma$. Hence, $\mu_n(E'') \rightarrow \mu(E'')$ for all $E'' \in \Sigma'$ such that $\mu(\delta E'')=0$. Hence, $\widetilde{\mu}_n \implies \widetilde{\mu}$. $\int\limits_{E'} f d\mu_n=\int\limits_{E'} f d\widetilde{\mu}_n \rightarrow\int\limits_{E'} f d\widetilde{\mu}=\int\limits_{E'} f d\mu$ follows immediately.

I'm not sure if this is correct. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Maybe try to find a counterexample before you try to prove that the statement is true.

Comment: This of course is false unless $f$ is continuous and bounded. For example, [moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157761/121671) do not transfer week by weak convergence in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your conclusion to hold it is necessary that $\mu_n(E') \to \mu (E')$. But this need not be true.

Counter-example: $E=[0,1], \mu_n=\delta_{1/n}, \mu=\delta_0, f=1$ and $E'=\{0\}$.